# Changing data-method with javascript does not change what method the ajax calls users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ujs

I've run into a very strange issue that I'm having a tough time fixing. In my view, I have a link with `data-remote="true"` and `data-method="delete"`. When I click the link, I can see a `DELETE` request to my rails server. The JS code returned then changes this link's properties, among which are the `href` and `data-method`.

Upon clicking this link again, my server is receiving a request to the new `href`, but with the old `data-method`, even though I have changed it from `DELETE` to `POST` (it still sends a `DELETE` request).

If I refresh the page, however, the HTML is the same as the "new" HTML (changed with my returned JS), but it actually sends the right request type. This is why the issue is puzzling me.

Comment: same problem here; i'll update once i find a solution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found a solution: Make sure you use the **jQuery Element.data()** Method for setting html data-attributes like "data-method" and so forth.

```
$(this).data('method', 'post'); # sets "data-method" attribute to "post"
$(this).data('method', 'delete'); # sets "data-method" attribute to "delete"

# "this" refers to the clicked link element for example
```